# Add class to parent when a descendant class is present

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to dynamically add styling to an element based on when a descendant has a specific class. I understand that this can only be done with javascript which isn't really my department.

Although I've been looking around for some copy paste solutions I now resort to creating this thread as I feel many answers listed here may be outdated and focused on compatibility.

I am no expert on the subject but i read that this can be done quite easily for modern browsers without using jquery and I only need it to work on modern browsers.

```
<ul class="the-parent">
    <li class="the-descendant"></li>
</ul>
```

What happens is that a Wordpress plugin is adding/removing class "opened" to "the-descendant" on interaction with the menu but does not provide me a way to style the parent based on this interaction.

Comment: Based on your example, what ***exactly*** do you want to do, and ***when*** exactly do you want that to happen?

Comment: I have a menu that is created by a 3rd party plugin. I need to be able to style parent menu links depending on whether a menu link is expanded to show the children links. Parent links have triggers(arrows) that you click to expand/close these parent menu links. There's a class that is being added to child element that is being expanded and it is the only thing that I can use as far as I can tell. CSS has no parent selector so I assume that JS is the only way. I have no knowledge in JS so I cant tell what is the best practice to solve this problem. At this point I am glad to get any advice.

Answer (score 1):

For what I read from your question, you'd need to set up a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the child node, then watch for attribute changes on the `class`  attribute:

```js
// Get a reference to the Node you need to observe classList changes on
const targetNode = document.querySelector('.child');

// Set up the configuration for the MutationObserver
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit
const config = { 
  attributes: true, 
  attributeFilter: ['class'],
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationsList, observer) => {
    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'class') {
            mutation
              .target
              .closest('.parent')
              .classList
              .toggle('orange');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
// observer.disconnect();
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
}

.parent.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.child {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent::after,
.child::after {
  content: '"'attr(class)'"';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" onclick="this.classList.toggle('clicked');">child css class: </div>
  parent css class: 
</div>
```

Remember it's important to disconnect the observer when you no longer need it, otherwise it stays active even if the [observed node is removed from the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#Observation_follows_nodes_when_disconnected).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Maybe you can tell me if I should attempt this at all. I am a little concerned that even though it is doable it may not be a good practice to solve such a problem in this way.